# Github actions on cloud run --allow-unauthenticated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-cloud-run, flags

I have github actions pipline on cloud run with --allow-unauthenticated flag but when instance is created Authentication is on "Require authentication" mode instead of "Allow unauthenticated invocations".

```
flags: |
  --port=8000
  --allow-unauthenticated
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You must be authenticated to deploy Cloud RUn.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
flags: '--allow-unauthenticated'
```

UPD: One important thing here is that your service account needs to have **run.services.setIamPolicy** permission to configure authentication on a Cloud Run service.

Details: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/managing-access#make-service-public

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using [deploy-cloudrun](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun). From README.md:

> flags: (Optional) Space separate list of other Cloud Run flags. This can be used to access features that are not exposed via this GitHub Action.

So it should be:

```
flags: '--port=8000 --allow-unauthenticated'
```